# How to pass implicit objects in a user defined method in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to access implicit objects in a user defined method in JSP.

Here is my code :

```
<%@ page import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest  %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<% %>
<%! public void setUserName()
{
String user = (String)request.getAttribute("user"); 

getUserName(user);}
```

How to access these objects in the method?

Comment: This is not an answer, but really, really, learn about the JSTL and the JSP EL, learn about the MVC architecture, and never, ever, put any line of Java code in a JSP again. That was the way to go 19 years ago. But the world has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

We **can’t use JSP implicit objects** in a method defined in JSP because they are local to service method and added by JSP Container while translating JSP page to servlet source code. **JSP Declarations code goes outside the service method** and used to create class level variables and methods and hence can’t use JSP implicit objects.

It's only the code written inside the scriptlet tags that goes into the _jspService() method and thus can directly access the implicit objects.

Comment: Yes , I do know that these are local to _jspService() method and my problem is that I am not able to delcare global variable in JSP page and to set the value of that variables , I need to access implicit objects . So , I want to know if there is any way for doing it ?

Comment: Ok. In that case, what if you write public void setUserName(HttpServletRequest request){} and call this method from a scriptlet like setUserName(request)?